# Why is my loop not populating the page with my custom taxonomy terms from my custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, pagination

Why is my loop not populating the page with my custom taxonomy terms from my custom post type? Currently it is displaying an empty box instead of pulling in the custom taxonomy terms from my custom post type `series`. I am at a complete loss as to why this is. Any assistance that could be provided would be much appreciated!

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'taxonomy'=> 'series',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'orderby'    => 'ID', 
        'order'      => 'DESC'
    );

    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>



        <div class="block_item article">
            <div  class="article_image" style="background: url('<?php the_field('series_artwork', $term); ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: 50%;"></div>
            <h4 class="section_label"><?php the_field('date', $term); ?></h4>
            <div class="block_item_content">
                <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'series'); ?>" class="button_styling">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

<?PHP endwhile; endif; ?>


<div class="clear"></div>

<?php // Pagination
if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

Comment: Taxonomies aren't posts. Instead of using `WP_Query` you'll need to use a function to get taxonomy terms instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the post type in argument and need to use the taxonomy tag properly. You can try the following args variable.

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'series', //Specify the post type here
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => '', //specify the taxonomy name
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => '', //Specify the slug of what you want from the taxonomy
                'operator'  => 'IN',
            )
        )
        'orderby'    => 'ID', 
        'order'      => 'DESC'
    );
```